# Node js stream file content and stop reading

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream, tail

I need to stream a log file to my frontend from node js backend and when the user leaves the page stops reading file, I was able to stream ok with tail-stream module and with require('child_process').spawn running tail -f command, but the backend remains running after leaving the page.
What can I do to stop the backend script that keeps watching the file?

here is an example that works as I said before.

```js
var sys = require('sys')
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var filename = process.argv[2];
if (!filename)
  return sys.puts("Usage: node <server.js> <filename>");

var tail = spawn("tail", ["-f", filename]);

http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  sys.puts("new connection..");
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});
  tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(new Date());
  res.write(data);
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Thanks in advance.